# Listar registros sem referência em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho três tabelas:
-**clientes**
-**planos**
-**servicos**

Na tabela **servicos** tenho servico_A, servico_B e servico_C que são relacionados na tabela **planos**.

Eu preciso listar todos os clientes que não possuem um plano com servico_C. Mesmo que ele tenha outros planos com outros serviços, ele não deve ser listado.

```
SELECT
p.codcliente
FROM
planos p
LEFT JOIN servicos se ON  p.codser = se.codser
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON p.codcliente = c.codcliente
WHERE
#ele nao tenha nenhum servico_C
ORDER BY p.codcliente
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `EXISTS` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM clientes c ON 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT p.codcliente
                    FROM planos p
                         INNER JOIN servicos se ON  p.codser = se.codser
                   WHERE p.codcliente = c.codcliente
                     AND p.descricao = 'servico_C')
 ORDER BY p.codcliente
```

Tomei a liberdade de deduzir o nome da coluna com a descrição do serviço, mas você deve mudar para o nome real.

> **[EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php)**
>
> A condição `EXISTS` do `MySQL` é usada em combinação com uma `subquery` e é considerada uma condição a ser cumprida se a `subquery` retornar ao menos uma linha.

No caso da `query` apresentada utilizamos uma `subquery` verificando se existe algum plano ligado ao serviço `servico_C` **E** ao código do cliente(`codcliente`) e utilizamos no `EXISTS`. Isso retornaria todos os clientes que **TEM** planos com `servico_C`, por isso utilizamos o **NOT** antes do `EXISTS`, invertendo assim a seleção.

Comment: Só para um entendimento mais amplo: A sub-query retorna um array com todos os valores encontrados, e a cláusula **NOT EXISTS** consulta se nesses valores retornados ele encontra, neste caso, o p.codcliente?

Comment: @RafaelSilva adicionei uma explicação mais detalhada